# Breadcrumbs - don't show current node

Tags: asp.net, sitemappath

With the SiteMapPath control (navigation breadcrumbs), is there any way to NOT show the current node you are on?  I only want to show the parents.  There is a property to `RenderCurrentNodeAsLink`, but not what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an empty [CurrentNodeTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.currentnodetemplate.aspx):

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="yourSiteMapPath" runat="server">
    <CurrentNodeTemplate>
    </CurrentNodeTemplate>
</asp:SiteMapPath>
```